# Python socket subprocess

Tags: python, sockets

i created a Server-client chat & subprocess shell. 
The problem is when i sent to the client 'cmd' , 'python' or some command that can be executed inside the cmd, the program is crash.
what can i do ? i tried everything. set blocking, set timeout .. all.

Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket() #TCP SOCKET //By Default
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",5555))
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = s.accept() #Connection Object &  ip
print "[+]New Connection:",addr
while True:
    command = raw_input('Shell>>')
    conn.send(command)
    print conn.recv(1024)
```

Client:

```
http://pastebin.com/EcFhDd5Z
```

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with the socket but the way you call Popen. Give the complete traceback of the error you are getting.

Comment: @syntonym Hey. thanks for replay! what error do you mean? the program just stuck. from example - the server , shell >>> cmd
the client got the message , and pass it to the subprocess, but the subprocess don't return anything.

Comment: You need to call communicate on the process [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: @syntonym I will immediately read this. but can you please have an exmaple to communicate ? i mean like code or something.

Comment: @syntonym I have python 2.6 , and he does not have timeout in subprocess.. what can i do?

Comment: python 2.6 has no support for the timeout parameter in the communicate function. Do you absolutly need it?

Comment: If this is a learning project I would advise for upgrading to 3.5.

Comment: Well , i want to finish this project on 2.6. there is no way to use timeout?

@syntonym